# Should you wrap your whole app with a React Context Provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to save a simple boolean + userID if a user is authenticated and have it accessible via [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider).

Many guides wrapped their root compoennt with the context Provider. To me it seems wastefull to wrap the whole app. On the other hand I need this information to be available in all my main pages.

**Does it have any negative consequenses to wrap your whole app with a React Context Provider?**

Example:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <MyProvider>
            <div className="App">
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to my web store</h1>
                <ProductList />
            </div>
        </MyProvider>
    );
}
```

}

I used [this guide](https://www.toptal.com/react/react-context-api) as a reference.

I do not have any experiences in React Redux so this might just natural to everyone who has used this framework before.

Researching Google brings up many guides on how to implement React Context or use HOC but the 15 I clicked did not answer my question.

Comment: You can wrap whole app in provider. React-redux recommends the same (https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#providing-the-store), so you may consider it acceptable practice

Comment: If you're planning to use context throughout your application, then yes.

Comment: Write is as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Fyodor pointed it out in his comment:

> You can wrap whole app in provider. React-redux recommends the same
>   (react-redux.js.org/introduction/…), so you may consider it acceptable
>   practice