# Where to put Context Provider in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, gatsby, react-context

I need to run some functions (eg. Office UI Fabric React's [`initializeIcons()`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/using-icons)) and AXIOS call (eg. retrieve the logged-in user with Context API) only the first time the site is hit, then store the retrieved values in the React Context and make it available to the whole application.

Gatsby is wrapping my pages' content in a **Layout**, like:

```jsx
const IndexPage = () =>
<Layout>
   Body of Index Page...
</Layout>
```

```jsx
const AnotherPage = () =>    
<Layout>
   Body of Another Page...
</Layout>
```

with **Layout** being like:

```jsx
const Layout = ({ children }) =>
<>
    <Header /> 
    <main>{children}</main>
    <Footer />
</>
```

I know where I can **NOT** put my Context:

- **around the pages** (or it will be executed everytime the page is hit, and also not available to the other pages):

  ```jsx
  const IndexPage = () =>
  <MyContextProvider>
      <Layout>
         Context Available here
      </Layout>
  </MyContextProvider>
  ```

  ```jsx
  const AnotherPage = () =>    
  <Layout>
      Context NOT available here
  </Layout>
  ```
- **in the Layout** (or it will be executed every time):

  ```jsx
  const Layout = ({ children }) =>
  <MyContextProvider>
      <Header /> 
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
  </MyContextProvider>
  ```

I suppose I need a root `<app>` object to surround with my Context Provider, but what's a clean way to achieve that with Gatsby?

**Where should I put my Context Provider?**

Comment: [Here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/) is a great blog post from the official Gatsby blog that could be useful to solve what you need.

Comment: Thank you @LionelT. That's basically what I've tried, with the exclusion of **localStorage** (which is fine for saving a theme, but not for the logged in user AFAIK). 
I can use the **sessionStorage** (but then I'd need to deal with two different users logging from the same pc subsequently and without closing the browser...), I just hoped there's a way to "store" the Axios call's result and avoid executing it again - without resorting to some HTML5 storage... thanks anyway, I'll explore it ASAP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You define a root layout. In contrast to the normal layout there are no "visible" page elements defined but hidden stuff you need on every page like ContextProviders, React Helmet, themes, etc:

`RootLayout.jsx`:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet />
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <ContextProvider>
            {children}
          </ContextProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Gatsby calls this root layout implicitly via `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` and applies it to each of your pages. Those two identical lines of code are all you need for Gatsby to handle the rest for you.

`gatsby-browser.js`:

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => <RootLayout>{element}</RootLayout>;
```

`gatsby-ssr.js`:

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => <RootLayout>{element}</RootLayout>;
```

**Summary:**

- You put your Context Provider in a root layout.

**References:**

- I asked related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829091/should-you-wrap-your-whole-app-with-a-react-context-provider) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875219/how-to-keep-or-resupply-react-context-in-a-gatsby-site). The code I provided in this answer is the solution to your and my question. It is good coding practice adapted from frameworks such as React Redux to wrap your whole app with the Context Provider if your whole app needs this information.
- The [blog post](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/) @Lionel T mentioned.

Comment: OK, the sentence in the answer to your other question (`There's no built-in mechanism for persisting state between page loads, so you'll need to reach for another tool for that`) makes the point that I'd need to "manually" implement some cookie or sessionStorage solution for the Auth part. At least now I'm sure there's nothing out of the box for that in Gatsby, thank you

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, correct. My solution was implementing json web tokens in order to recognize a recurring user as the answer you mentioned suggested.

Comment: this worked for me but it loads all my layouts twice which has caused some issues.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the APIs Gatsby provides (through `gatsby-browser.js`) to **run a function only once** are:

[onClientEntry](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry)

```
export const onClientEntry = () => {
    console.log("Browser started!")
    // Put here run-only-once functions 
}
```

[onInitialClientRender](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onInitialClientRender)

```
export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
    console.log("First rendering completed!")
    // Put here run-only-once functions which need rendered output
}
```